# How to add a fully stretched yellow container after every 10 grids in a Flutter Grid Builder?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter application where I'm using a Grid Builder to display a grid of items. After every 10 grids, I want to insert a fully stretched yellow container to separate the sections. For example, the first row should contain grids 1 to 5, the second row should contain grids 6 to 10, and then a yellow container should be inserted before displaying grids 11 to 15 on the next row. This pattern should continue until the end of the grid (e.g., 100 grids).

I have attached the current code and an image for reference. Could you please guide me on how to achieve this functionality? Thank you in advance.

```
GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 100,
        gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 5,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          if ((index + 1) % 11 == 0) {
            // Add yellow color stretch container after every 10th container
            return Container(
              color: Colors.yellow,
              height: 50,
              width: double.infinity,
            );
          } else {
            // Regular square rounded shape container
            return Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              child: Center(
                child: Text('${index + 1}'),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      )
```

[image]

Comment: If you wanna use dynamic sized widget, you should use [flutter_staggered_grid_view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_staggered_grid_view) instead of gridview.

Comment: May you please write a demo code? @BG Park

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my take on it... using .skip and .take for the subgroups:

```
final items = Iterable<int>.generate(47).toList();

class Body extends StatelessWidget {
  const Body({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => ListView.separated(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          final group = items.skip(index * 10).take(10).toList();
          if (group.isEmpty) return null;
          return GridView.count(
            crossAxisCount: 5,
            shrinkWrap: true,
            children: [
              for (final item in group)
                Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  child: Center(
                    child: Text('$item'),
                  ),
                )
            ],
          );
        },
        separatorBuilder: (context, index) => const Divider(
          thickness: 32,
          height: 40,
          color: Colors.yellow,
        ),
        itemCount: (items.length / 10).ceil(),
      );
}
```

Comment: This is better as I don't have to use external package. Thank You @Randal Schwartz

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple example.

```
class TestScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // The number you want to sperate the data.
    const int splitCount = 10;

    // Items that you have. Change this to suit your conditions.
    final List<int> items = List.generate(
      100,
      (index) => index,
    );

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('Staggered GridView'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: TestStaggerdGridView(
            items: items,
            splitCount: splitCount,
            crossAxisCount: 5,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestStaggerdGridView extends StatelessWidget {
  const TestStaggerdGridView({
    super.key,
    required this.items,
    required this.splitCount,
    required this.crossAxisCount,
  });

  /// Items that you have. Change this to suit your conditions.
  final List<int> items;

  /// The number you want to seprate the items.
  final int splitCount;

  /// The number of cell count in an axis.
  final int crossAxisCount;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final int addedCount = items.length ~/ (splitCount + 1);

    return StaggeredGrid.count(
      axisDirection: AxisDirection.down,
      crossAxisCount: crossAxisCount,
      children: List.generate(
        items.length + addedCount,
        (index) {
          if ((index + 1) % (splitCount + 1) == 0) {
            return StaggeredGridTile.count(
              mainAxisCellCount: 1,
              crossAxisCellCount: crossAxisCount,
              child: _stretchedItem(),
            );
          } else {
            int itemIndex = (index - (index ~/ (splitCount + 1)));

            return StaggeredGridTile.count(
              mainAxisCellCount: 1,
              crossAxisCellCount: 1,
              child: _normalItem(itemIndex),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _normalItem(int itemIndex) {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
      child: Center(child: Text('${itemIndex + 1}')),
    );
  }

  Widget _stretchedItem() {
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The list changes to 91 elements. It can create problems as data is been load from Database. @BG Park

Comment: Just add the count of list in list.generate like ```totalCount + addedCount```.  The total count is 100 and the addedCount is ```totalCount ~/  11``` in this example. And use ```int itemIndex = (index - (index ~/ 11))``` as a index of item you have.

Comment: If you think it's complicated, just create multiple GridViews with 10 item count.

Comment: May you please re-edit the code? @BG Park

Comment: @RajA I changed the code.